# Comparing records from dstream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a case with Apache Spark where I like to analyse sensorstreams. The stream exists of sensordata from a variety of sensors but all push the same kind of data.

From this stream I like to know for each sensor how long a specific value is below a certain threshold. A sensor submits records every x seconds containing: timestamp and value. I like to extract the intervals at which a sensor is below the value to get the duration, starttime of interval, endtime of interval and average value.
I'm not sure about the proper ('Sparkish') way to extract the duration, start- and endtime of every interval from all connected sensors.

The approach I currently use is a foreach-loop with some state variables to uniquely mark each record if it is part of an interval from a specific sensor. When the records have been marked a map-reduce approach is used to extract the needed info. But I don't feel comfortable with the foreach-loop because it does not fit in the map-reduce approach and therefore does not scale well when work is distributed among workers.
In more general terms I'm facing the challenge comparing individual records in a rdd and records from different dstreams.

Anyone recognises such a (trivial) case and knows a better/more elegant approach to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the best way to do this is by using mapWithState(). This function offers an elegant and flexible way to maintain state among values from successive dstreams.